Image display issue in SwiftUI
I have an Image view that displays images with aspectRatio .fit in the middle of the screen (other elements will display above & below images). Then, a scaling effect is applied to them. This works well for most of the images that have wider dimensions but one of the images seen here displays with gaps from the edges of the screen when run on an iPhone 16 simulator leading to an ugly scaling effect. My guess is that I'd have to detect if an image to be shown fits the screen width and if not, resize it before display. Would this be the only way to fix it? Please advise.
struct FancyViewer: View {
    private let imageName = "dragon"
    private let animDuration = 5.0
    @State private var imageScale: CGFloat = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.width * 1.5)
                    .scaleEffect(imageScale)
                    .animation(.linear(duration: animDuration), value: imageScale)
                    .clipped()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .foregroundStyle(.thinMaterial)
                .overlay {
                    Color.clear
                        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .onAppear {
            imageScale = CGFloat.random(in: 1.0...1.3)
        }
    }
}


Why have you written .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.width * 1.5)? What are you trying to do with that? I would replace that and aspectRatio with .scaledToFit().

Ignore my previous comment. If I didn't set the frame, with additional elements added above the image like multiple Text("Hello") for example, it would display margins horizontally. Here is a screenshot with using frame and aspectRatio and here's the incorrect display using just .scaledToFit.

I think you should edit your question to include those images.

Okay so if you have other content on top of the image, the desired result becomes more unclear. If you scale up the image so that there are no gaps, what will happen to the other content? Do you want the image to cover up the other content?

Sorry, StackOverflow is glitching on mobile so I could not attach images directly into the post. No, the images should not cover up the other content. I've added the clipped() modifier so I think that should take care of it. So to clarify, I'd like for the images to fill the width, even overflow a bit such that they either scale up further with animation or scale down to identity with animation & not have gaps showing.

So if I understand correctly, you want the image to fit when the W:H ratio of the image is larger than the W:H ratio of the available space, and you want the image to fill when the W:H ratio of the image is smaller than the W:H ratio of the available space. Is that correct?

If you want to scale-to-fit in some cases but scale-to-fill in others, depending on the aspect ratio, then using ViewThatFits may be a way to solve. See Image is being rendered with 1/3 of screen width for some examples of how it can be used.

aspectRatio will try to resize the image to fit the frame you set. If the image is too tall to fit the frame's height, there will be gaps on the sides.
If you just use a ridiculously large number as the height of the frame, only ridiculously tall (very low W:H ratio) images will be able to exceed that height and create gaps on the sides.
Also, to clip the image within the available space, you should put the image as an overlay of some view that fills the available space (e.g. Color.clear), and clip that view. clipped on the Image will not do anything because the Image always fits inside the frame you gave it.
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Color.clear
            .overlay {
                Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(height: 100000000)
                    .scaleEffect(imageScale)
                    .animation(.linear(duration: animDuration), value: imageScale)
            }
            .clipped()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background {
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .foregroundStyle(.thinMaterial)
            .overlay {
                Color.clear
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    .onAppear {
        imageScale = CGFloat.random(in: 1.0...1.3)
    }
}


Two observations: (1) The comment about clipping an image is not always true - if a frame is set on an image that is scaled-to-fill, clipping will remove the overflow. Indeed, clipping an image that is scaled-to-fit inside an overlay will normally not do anything, the only reason it is useful here is because of the very tall frame being set on the image. (2) Since Color.clear is being used as the footprint in the solution here, it will always consume the full height of the display, so the Spacer are redundant (except that the VStack will also add a little spacing top and bottom).

@BenzyNeez You are right. I included the Spacers to give more context as to where this code should be, but I guess I will just include the whole body.
